# Storing SQL queries in table and run them on-the-fly when selecting - Possible? Good practice?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm currently thinking about a database schema in MySQL where I store `SELECT` queries into a certain table column, just to execute them on-the-fly when getting selected, and having the result passed instead of the actual query.

Would this be possible somehow? Or may this be bad practice? Is it even technically possible to have a result table passed to a single field, at least so I could run the query through PDO to get back a nested result array? Are there any alternatives?

I've read that this may be achieved through stored procedures, and although I grip the concept of those I can't think of how I could use those to achieve that.

Comment: A textbook example of an XY Problem. WHY do you want such a strange mess?

Comment: Let's say I wanted to store some simple JSON data instead. This data isn't constant though and depends on the content of some other tables,  which made me thought that this would better be handled by a query. The problem is that each row depends on tables in different ways, which means I can't just write one global query to bind values to for handling all rows, but need a set of queries where each handles its own row. Is there a better solution to this, or am I just having a bad design? I guess it's worth to mention that I'm managing meta-data here.

Comment: this is a bad design for sure, as of the better implementation we cannot suggest anything due to the lack of information. From what you just said I only can guess that a database structure is flawed as well. Do you have you data normalized? Did you look into NoSQL solutions? Mongo, for example, does store json actually. But meh, again you are asking an XY problem. Describe the initial application for which you need these micro-jsons or whatever. better not in the comment but in a solid and a well-thought question

Comment: find the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949068/how-to-design-inherited-tables-with-different-columns-and-column-metadata-in-dat

Answer (score 2):

You could do this, but what purpose do you have for doing it?

I would suggest using views:

- The syntax should be valid when the view is created, unlike storing
  the SQL in a field which may have invalid syntax.
- It's easier to debug and modify.

For example, let's say one of the queries you want to store is:

```
SELECT product_category, COUNT(*) AS category_count
FROM product
GROUP BY product_category;
```

You can create a new "view" object that defines this query:

```
CREATE VIEW prod_cat_count AS
SELECT product_category, COUNT(*) AS category_count
FROM product
GROUP BY product_category;
```

Now, the object called "prod_cat_count" is stored in the database. Internally, the database just knows that "prod_cat_count" is equal to the SELECT query we mentioned. When the view is created, the database validates the syntax (checks that all columns exist, checks you haven't forgotten the GROUP BY, for example)

Then, whenever you want to get this data/run this query, you can run this statement (in SQL or in application code, for example):

```
SELECT product_category, category_count
FROM prod_cat_count;
```

If you then decide you want to change the way the product categories are counted, you can adjust the view:

```
SELECT product_category, COUNT(*) AS category_count
FROM product
GROUP BY product_category
ORDER BY product_category;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: How exactly would I use them? Store the view name instead and refer to the respective view in a subquery?

Comment: Yeah that's right. I'll update my answer to explain further.